# Stop Infinite event handling for ui tabs

Tags: jquery

I want to show an alert message if user click on second tan without submitting the form on the first tab, the problem I face of infinite alert messages that's show when user click on tab,
here is the code I write

```
 $(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        selected:<?php echo $param ?>,

        select: function(e, ui) {

            var thistab = ui;
            runMethod();

        }

    });

});
function runMethod(){
    if( $.trim($("#generalImportNo").text()) == "")
    {
        alert("You should fill all main information first.")                     
        $('#tabs').tabs({selected:1 });

    }
}
```

I try to use `stopPropagation` but it doesn't work, how can I prevent infinite event occuring ?!

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML for `#tabs` and `#generalImportNo`? When you say you tried `stopPropagation`, where did you add that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
...
select: function(e, ui) {
   var thistab = ui;
   return runMethod();
}
...
function runMethod(){
    if( $.trim($("#generalImportNo").text()) == "")
    {
       alert("You should fill all main information first.")                     
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If `select` event returns `false` then your tab won't be selected. <strike>I can't test right now, but that's what I did a long time ago.</strike> Also you may find
`$('#tabs').tabs({ disabled: [1, 2, 3], ... });` quite useful, it will prevent your users to click on unavailable tabs. To enable your tab through the code use `$('#tabs').tabs('enable', tabIndexToEnable);`

**UPD**: I created a quick [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n6FxB/), seems to work just fine.

**UPD2**: Here's another [one](http://jsfiddle.net/n6FxB/3/) just to show that everything works fine.

Comment: @PalAla see my update with a demo. Feel free to modify the demo in order to show what doesn't work there with your code.

Comment: @PalAla: As you have not posted the relevant HTML we don't know what `#generalImport` is. If it is an input text control you might want to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`. Updated demo from answer to include input check as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/n6FxB/2/

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, haha, just in time I modified my demo `:)`. Thanks though.